# SQL query using CASE to select certain rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as given below

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
colA | colB | colC | colD
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
1 | female | ... | ...
2 | male   | ... | ...
3 |        | ... | ...
4 | select | ... | ...
5 | dfd    | ... | ...
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I want to choose all rows with 'female' or 'male' in colB and also rows with empty or 'select' value in colB but want to rename it as 'unknown'. The resulting table should be:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
colA | colB | colC | colD
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
1 | female | ... | ...
2 | male   | ... | ...
3 | unknown| ... | ...
4 | uknown | ... | ...
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

My query was:

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC, colD FROM table 
where (colB in ('female','male') and 
        case when colB = '' then 'unknown'
             when colB = 'select' then 'unknown' end)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want:

```
SELECT colA,
       (CASE WHEN colB IN ('female', 'male') THEN colb ELSE 'unknown' END) as colB,
       colC, colD
FROM table 
WHERE colB in ('female', 'male', '') OR colB IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want rows with four values, but you want to present two cases differently.

Changing presentation of values should be done in the select-list.

```
SELECT colA, 
  CASE WHEN colB IN ('','select') THEN 'unknown' ELSE colB END AS colB,      
  colC, colD 
FROM table
WHERE colB IN ('','select','female','male');
```